# Returning to main method?

Tags: java, methods, return, program-entry-point

I am having some trouble in my code on how to execute the main method as others.
here is a example of what I need:

```
(...)
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    hi();
    System.out.println("cake time!");
}
public static void hi ()
{
    main();
}
```

I would like to know how to run that "cake time!", substituting that "main();" in a nice way, in the same purpose of the "hi();"

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2):

You don't call `main()`. It is called for you when your app starts, and when you reach the end of it your app is finished. It makes no sense to call `main()`.

For what you need, you have a way available (you even used it in your subject):

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    hi();
    // The return from hi() executes the next line of code
    System.out.println("cake time!");
}
public static void hi ()
{
    // Do whatever hi() does here. When it's done, 
    // you automatically go back to the line after the one
    // that called you. (You "return" to the next line).
    // If the function returns a value (isn't void), you use 
    // the keyword 'return'.
}
```

Comment: return is also not required, automatically it will goto main.

Comment: @VenkateshAchanta: Yep. Clarified what I was intending to say instead. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get it very well... probably because of my high level of English. I want to make a "loop" in my program, but with return or not it doesn't work :/. Anyway thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: wait, after i read 8 times the same answer, I finally got it! Thanks for your time.